# Why is this graph a connected Eulerian one?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

In the well-known article of Oystein Ore titled "A problem regarding the tracing of graphs", Elemente der Mathematik, 6 (1951), 49-53, he proves that an Euler graph $G$ is arbitrarily traceable from the vertex $a$ iff every cylcle of $G$ contains $a$. In his proof, he assumes, on the way of contradiction, that a cycle $C$ does not contain $a$. Consider the graph $G_1=G-C$ which is Eulerian, since the vertices of both $G$ and $C$ are even and hence the same holds for $G_1$. Now, he says that $a$ is contained in a "maximal" component $G^{(a)}$ of $G_1$. Let $G_2=G^{(a)}+C$. He claims that this $G_2$ is a connected Eulerian graph......

My questions:

1. what is meant by a "maximal" component of a graph?
2. why is  $G_2$ a connected Eulerian graph?
   Thanks for any help!

Comment: Considering that the paper is from 1951, the meaning of the term "component" may have shifted. I guess he meant a connected subset of vertices, so "maximal component" would be what we call today "component". Then by definition $G^{(a)}$ is connected, and contains a vertex belonging to $C$, hence $G_2$ is connected. And $G^{(a)}$ is Eulerian (as a component of an Eulerian graph), as is $C$, hence $G_2$ is Eulerian.

Comment: @Guyslain Thanks for the comment. But I do not understand why $G^{(a)}$ contains a vertex belonging to $C$. Indeed, $G^{(a)}$ is a subset of $G_1$ which is disjoint from the cycle $C$.

Comment: Because $G$ is connected, there is a path in $G$ from any vertex of $C$ to $a$. Choose such a shortest path $P$, say from $v$ to $a$. Because it is shortest, any inner vertex of $P$ is not in $C$, hence $E(P) \cap E(C) = \emptyset$, and by that fact that $G^{(a)}$ is a maximal component of $G - C$, $P$ is a path in $G ^{(a)}$, thus $v \in V(G^{(a)})$.

Comment: @Guyslain OK! That works. Thanks a lot!